# How to display data with line breaks from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, character-encoding

I am storing user inputs in my DB unencoded, this includes line breaks in the data.
There are no `\n` or `<br>`'s in the inputs when then displaying the data again so the line breaks are lost.

I have tried wrapping the output in `htmlspecialchars` but it has not made a difference.

How can I accurately display this content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br):

```
$data = nl2br($data);
```

This adds HTML line breaks `<br>` before PHP line breaks `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also Used this.
PHP generates HTML. You may want:

```
echo "foo";
echo "<br />\n";
echo "bar";
```

I think, It is used full to you.

Thank You..